# Decode amf3 object using PHP

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, amf

My flash code:

```
var request=new URLRequest('http://localhost/test.php');
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
var data = new URLVariables();
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
bytes.objectEncoding = ObjectEncoding.AMF3;
//write an object into the bytearray
bytes.writeObject( 
      { myString:"Hello World"} 
);
data.data = bytes;
request.data = data;

var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);
urlLoader.load(request);

function onCompleteHandler(evt:Event):void {
 trace(evt.target.data);
}
```

PHP code:

```
define("AMF_AMF3",1); 
$data = $_POST['data'];
echo amf_decode($data, AMF_AMF3);
```

Basically I need to send an AMF3 object from Flash to PHP and unserialize it. I'm using AMFEXT extension but couldn't get it to work. Any idea?

Comment: *(sidenote)* The officially supported library is Zend_AMF is http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.amf.introduction.html

Comment: Given the performance of amfext I would like to explore that option =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you had a look at AMFPHP: http://www.amfphp.org/

"AMFPHP is a free open-source PHP implementation of the Action Message Format(AMF). AMF allows for binary serialization of Action Script (AS2, AS3) native types and objects to be sent to server side services. AMFPHP is challenged with implementing the entire AMF protocol to be an alternative to Flex Data Services (AMF3) and Flash Remoting (AMF0)"

Comment: Yes I'm aware of AMFPHP but I don't need the remote function of it. I just need a way to encode/decode AMF3 data in PHP..

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one - http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-amf3/

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple AMF3 Serializer/Deserialize in PHP for my project FlashMOG:
[here](http://flashmog.net/server_source_docs/current/__filesource/fsource_FlashMOG_FlashMOG_Server_fm_includesclassesSerializer_AMF3.php.html#a61)

It would need a bit of adaptation.

Answer (score -1):

just take a look at the AMFPHP project, I used it on a chat project and it is really simple to use and efficient.