# php unserialize as3's writeObject

Tags: php, actionscript-3, object, serialization

```
aobj = new ByteArray();
aobj.writeObject(Obj);   //Obj is a usual as3 Object {param1:123,......}
```

what I receive in php is

```
Param1ЃЙ]Param2     Param3
    Param32 Param4
```

How to read (unserialize) object data that has been written in as3?

Comment: Please [**`edit`**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43392130/edit) to show full `Obj` content and also the PHP code used for reading object.

Comment: AMF3 (the format used by AS3 to write objects into ByteArray) is a byte-packed serialization format. I strongly advise against using AMF3 format as a carrier format between AS3 application and any other technology. I did such a thing in the past and it wasn't a pleasure at all. A lot of pain, to be more precise. Consider using JSON instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decode amf3 object using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628369/decode-amf3-object-using-php)

Comment: Can you be a little bit more precise than "A lot of pain"? Why you advise against AMF? I've used [AMFPHP](https://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/) and remember it working like a charm. Using JSON would be significantly slower.

Comment: @Organis in my case `json` is a trouble, especially for the unfriendly behavior with a binary data.

Comment: @PawełAudionysos It was 8 years ago, in 2009, we had complicated backend: socket C daemon for active requests and HTTP PHP server as MySQL DB layer. For C daemon we basically had to create our own version of AMF parser/serializer, while AMFPHP wasn't perfect back then and worked in one direction only (I don't remember which one). Choosing AMF3 was probably the worst technical mistake for that project. I'm glad to hear it's all better now.

Comment: As with every binary format, writing your own parser could be tricky. Give one bit wrong offset and all your output looks like garbage. I can't remember right now when I used it (also not recently), but luckly I didn't need to do that with AMFPHP.

Comment: ok let's stay with the json ))